# Load newly installed modules in python script

Tags: python, django, python-module

I am writing a python script which automatically sets up a django web server environment.

In the script, I am installing a new modules using

```
for package in packages:
    os.system("%s %s" % ('easy_install', package))
```

This works fine. My only issue is that I want to use these newly installed packages in the same script using

```
package = __import__(package)
```

This does not work though, and I receive an ImportError: No module named reportlab (for example)

If I run the script again, the script works as I assume all of the newly installed packages are on the system path. I was hoping there is a way that I can import the new modules without restarting the script though.

I tried reload(sys) but it didn't help me. I can hack it by manually appending to sys.path or by starting a new python script using os.system(), but I would prefer a cleaner solution.

Answer (score 3):

There cannot be a cleaner solution.  You're installing a package, which leads to an update to the system path.  You must either tinker with the path or start a sub-script that works in a new environment.

Also.  Don't use `os.system`.  Please use `subprocess`.

The least risky way to do this is to have a "master" script which only does two kinds of things.

1. Use `subprocess.Popen` to run the sequence of easy_install scripts.
2. Use `subprocess.Popen` to do the rest of the work after all the easy_install scripts.  Since this is a separate process, it can build a separate Python PATH with all of the new packages in it.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Fabric](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.3.4/index.html), by the looks of things it'll make your life a lot easier.
Django [integration](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.3.4/api/contrib/django.html?highlight=django#fabric.contrib.django) here.

Answer (score 0):

You need to reload `site` module, not `sys`:
["Importing this module will append site-specific paths to the module search path and add a few builtins."](http://docs.python.org/2/library/site.html)

Also, consider using of `importlib.import_module` instead of `__import__`:
[This is an advanced function that is not needed in everyday Python programming, unlike importlib.import_module().](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#__import__)